# Django view variables based on url

Tags: django, url, view, model

I'm just starting off with python so bear with me.

Lets say this is my model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('name'))
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_('location'))
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('start time'))
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('end time'))
    sales_start = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('sales start'))
    sales_end = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('sales end'))
    event_active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('event active'))
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('price'))
    maximum = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('maximum'))
    information = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name=_('information'))
    logo = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_('logo'), blank=True, upload_to='img/%Y/%m/%d')
```

What I would like to accomplish is make a single page and fill it with data from an 'event', I would like to get this event by getting the Id from the url.

I'm not sure on how to do this as I don't understand certain parts of the documentation as I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: This is basic Django functionality, fundamental to every single site, and is fully explained in the tutorial. What exactly didn't you understand from that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman There was something wrong at a different place so I thought I was doing something wrong so I asked it here. The answer din't work at first but then I discovered what was wrong and fixed it. And to be honest... The answer Martin gave was very clear for me and helped alot more then the tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
# urls.py
# note 'event_id' will be passed as argument to 'show_event' view.
url(r'events/(?P<event_id>\d+)/$', 'show_event', name='show_event')


# views.py
def show_event(request, event_id):
    ...
    # this will return a 404 response is case event with given id is not found
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id)
    ...
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'event': event})


# template.html
<h1>Welcome to the event {{event.name}}</h1>
```

You will use URLs in this way: `yourdomain.com/events/123`.
That would pull `123` event id from URL and render `template.html` sending the proper event object in the template context, so you can render it as you want.

Comment: Thanks! I needed to change some other stuff to make it work (some stuff that needed change for sure) that's why it took me so long to answer. Very clear and useful!

Answer (score 0):

So your urls.py will need to be designed to except a regular expression of anything your page name could be.  In the example provided by Martin you can also have a regular expression match text instead of just a number.